# my regex to find opening braces at the beginning of a block is not working

Tags: regex, bash, perl, grep, backreference

I just started learning perl about a week ago. But i have a basic knowledge of regex features like back-references, look arounds etc.
So i wrote a small regex to match strings in an array (this array represents every line of a file) that has only '{' as a printable character.

my regex goes like:

```perl
for my $f_line (@file_lines) {
    my @opening_brace;
    if ($f_line =~ /(^[[:blank:]]*(?={))({[[:blank:]]*$)/) {
      @opening_brace = $2;
      print "opening brace : @opening_brace \n"; 
    }
  }
```

However, my regex couldn't get me into the if block even though it worked fine with `grep` when i tested it against the target file.

What am i doing wrong?

i tried:

```bash
echo "{       " | grep -P '(^[[:blank:]]*(?={))({[[:blank:]]*$)'
```

and got:

`{`

Comment: What is the expected output of your `grep -P`?

Comment: the bash result

Comment: I get `opening brace : {` when I run that after adding a `my @file_lines = ("{       ");`...

Comment: Please show input sample and what you expect to match from it. Also show a sample of input that should *not* match.

Answer (score 2):

The regex, copied here verbatim, works

```
echo "{   " | perl -wnlE'say $1 if /^[[:blank:]]*(?={)({[[:blank:]]*$)/'
```

Prints a line: `{`

But there is no `$2`, used in the question,<sup>†</sup> as the shown regex captures only once. It seems that you expect the `(?=...)` of the lookahead to also capture: it doesn't.  We need extra parenthesis for that, `(?=({))`.  So either add that to your regex, or keep the regex as it is and use `$1` in the code.  (Unless the data itself is in fact different than what the question implies.)

Then, I don't see why use a lookahead *and* then an actual consuming match for that very pattern.  (An exercise?)

---

It came up in comments that input may contain a newline, like `{\n`.  The regex from the question, used above, still works.

One way to readily see that is to remove the `-l` switch (so use `-wnE`), which `chomp`s a newline.  Then the regex is applied to a string ending with a newline, which `echo` adds -- and we still get a match and capture.  (The [POSIX Character class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#POSIX-Character-Classes)  of `[[:blank:]]` does not match a linefeed.)

---

<sup>†</sup> A general note. That `$2` in the question is *assigned* to an array, as `@opening_brace = $2`.  That *can* be done and after that the array has that one element.  However, it is very misleading, and assigning to an array overwrites what may have been in it.

We add to array by `push @arrayname, LIST`, so in this case `push @opening_brace, $2;` (but see the discussion above regarding that `$2`). Or correct that `@opening_brace` to a scalar `$opening_brace` if the character `@` for an array is there by a mistake.

Comment: With `say "|$1|" if ...` one can see that spaces are captured as well

Answer (score 0):

Oh
I just found a fix.
It appears my file 'lines' are not really lines.
The problem lies in the subtle difference in logical lines of a string and literal anchors denoting the start and end of a file line which were created when I pushed the lines into an array as strings.
Thanks for the help tho

Comment: SOLUTION: providing the enhanced line anchor mode feature ///m makes it all go away

Comment: "_SOLUTION_"  -- well, not quite: there is no `$2` in what you show in the question.  As the question never shows the actual input I can't tell about the rest of this answer. The `/m` modifier makes regex treat a string as multi-line so that anchors `^` and `$` match around newlines inside the string as well, not only the beginning and end of the string.  Do you have multiline strings in your input?

Comment: Yea, I do.
I converted some  '{' to '{\n' earlier in my code. which turns the string to a multiline right?

Comment: Yes, it does.  But if `\n` is at the end (with nothing behind it, like the end of a line in a file) then `$` still matches the end of string, by design.  By the phrasing in the question I thought it's only `{` (with spaces) -- if there's more to it then perhaps you could add some data to the question?

Comment: But your regex -- which I use in my answer -- still works, even if it's `{   \n` (instead of `{   `).  A clear way to see that is to remove the `-l` switch from my one-liner, so instead of `-wnlE` use `wnE`. (The `-l` removes a newline from end of input.)  Then the `echo`-ed string, with a newline (which `echo` adds), has that newline at the end and it's still matched (and captured) fine.